# CreateJS Collision Detection only once

Tags: collision-detection, createjs

I am working on a space invaders like game. I am having problems with my collision detection that it detects the collision to much so when I add score or set game over to many scores are added or the game is ended to many times. (While i just want to add a score once or end the game once).

I tried:
-remove the bullet object that hits the player.
-Change the x and y values of the bullet
-Remove the container of the bullets
-Set the size of the bullets to 0

All these things seem to still not work correctly.

```
for(var k = 0; k < enemyBullets.children.length; k++) { 

    if(enemyBullets.children[k].x >= character.x + characterWidth || enemyBullets.children[k].x + size <= character.x || enemyBullets.children[k].y >= character.y + characterHeight || enemyBullets.children[k].y + size <= character.y) 
    { 
        //not {
    }else {

        console.log("game over");
        for(var j = 0; j < enemyBullets.children.length; j++) { 
        enemyBullets.removeChildAt[j];
        }
        stage.removeChild(enemyBullets);

        enemyBullets.children[k].y = -20;
        enemyBullets.children[k].x = -20;
        size = 0;

        gameOver();
        }
    }
```

The game seems to run gameover to many times. I use the same code for adding score when the player bullet hit an enemy then it adds to much score.

Comment: You aren't breaking your loop, so it will run gameOver every iteration of the loop.

Comment: If I add "break;" after "gameOver();" gameover is still called about 12 times.

Comment: You are inside a second loop. You have to break the top loop. You can add a name to your loop and break that: `loopName:for(...) {  for(...)  { break loopName; } }`